# On double click on accordion, open modal in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular5

I'm using accordion and on double click of accordion I want to open modal. Since on single click it will expand the content, I want to use double click on that and open modal. Is it possible **DOUBLE CLICK ON ACCORDION**?

```
<ngb-accordion>
    <ngb-panel id="toggle-2" title="Second">
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
                  aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                  sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                  craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
                  occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
                  labore sustainable VHS.
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
 </ngb-accordion>
```

In this if I double click on title, modal should open.

Comment: you can use `(dblclick)` event. Sample [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NxeLBP55uaibQklOFioQ?p=preview)

Comment: I know there is a (dblclick) exists. I asked is it possible in accordion

Comment: which accordion you are using

Comment: ng-bootstrap accordion

Comment: can you add the code which you are trying, if possible have a working example please

Answer (score 0):

yes in pure javascript there is dblclick() event.

in angular, you can use like `(dblclick)="myFunction()"`

for more events look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Events)

Comment: It will be glad if u show some code with accordion double click